# Qt Designer-- How to add double click function to the Qslider button

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer, double-click

I have made a GUI using Qt designer. I want to add an option where I can double click the slider which will open a new window. My problem is I cannot assign double click to the Slider. How is it done?

Comment: You cannot do that directly from Designer, as there's no signal for double click. You can install an event filter on the slider from code and listen for `QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick` events, but I wouldn't suggest that, as it's not a very intuitive action for a slider, also because the first click would probably trigger a page up/down on the slider.

Comment: The slider is suppose to control intensity of led and on click give further details thats my idea

Comment: UX-wise, if you want a function to have further details, it should use a *different* control. You could use a small button on its size, or eventually add a context menu. As said, a click on the slider (if done *outside* the handle) will trigger a page up/down, so the user must be careful in doubleclicking the handle otherwise the value will be changed. In some platforms or style, the first click might even completely move the slider to a new position. The whole concept is not intuitive, and can be very annoying too, so I suggest you to find another option.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try that

Comment: A context-menu might be a better option. There's a [customContextMenuRequested signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) (inherited from QWidget) that can be connected in Qt Designer. You can also set the [contextMenuPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) via the Property Editor.

Comment: Can you give an example installing eventfilter on a Slider (already made from qtdesigner)